# tkinter scrollbar not scrolling fully

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm creating an application that requires a section of the screen to be able to scroll through it so I can place a database list within it, however it does not allow me to scroll through the entire list, (for the test I have a temporary list of labels as a replacement).

I get a few pixels of movement at best.

I'm aware that it's probably something simple that i'm missing out, but I'm multiple hours deep now and i mentally checked out a long time ago, cheers.

```
#making the frame everything acts in 
inventory_window=tk.Canvas(centre_column, width=962, height=700, bg=tertiery_colour, bd=0, relief="flat", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
inventory_window.place(x=10, y=83)

#frame scrollbar
inventory_scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(centre_column, orient="vertical", command=inventory_window.yview)
inventory_scrollbar.place(x=980, y=90, height=694)

#configuring the canvas
inventory_window.config(yscrollcommand=inventory_scrollbar.set)
inventory_window.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: inventory_window.configure(scrollregion=inventory_window.bbox("all")))

#adding a frame to the canvas
inventory_window_frame=tk.Frame(inventory_window,  width=965, height=703, bg=tertiery_colour, bd=0, relief="flat", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)

#setting the command of the window for scrolling, and placing it because OOP is stupid
inventory_window.create_window((0,0), window=inventory_window_frame, anchor=NW)

count=10
for i in range(100):
    pad_8=tk.Label(inventory_window_frame, text=str(count))
    pad_8.config(width=5, bg=primary_colour)
    pad_8.place(x=10, y=count)
    count=count+40
```

I expected to be able to scroll through 100 labels, it moves, but only a few pixels

Comment: You aren't updating the `scrollregion` with the inner frame changes size.

Comment: Also using `.place()` to add labels to `inventory_window_frame` does not adjust the size of `inventory_window_frame`.